# redirect_to does not work as expected on if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to figure out why my nil check fails when calling a method with no param, or a param id which yields no records.

```
@game = Game.where(:id => params[:id]).first

if @game.nil?
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

In console this works fine.

```
>> pp @game.nil?
=> true
```

In application this fails (it never redirects!), why?

## EDIT 1:

In console ( with param id nil or non existent record value):
This works:

```
unless Game.exists?(params[:id])
  raise('ok')
end
```

But not in the real life application :( I tried almost every way to check the record to be existent or valid, the code just runs past this check and continues as is

## EDIT 2:

Looking at some other code I noticed I used a return statement
IT seems to solve it with that so..

Works:

```
unless Game.exists?(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_path
  return
end
```

Fails:

```
unless Game.exists?(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Not quite sure why it needs an return after the redirect_to explicit

Comment: Can't tell you why, but a possible alternative might be to use the active record method `exists?` instead. Documentation found here: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F

Comment: Im on rails 4, I should update my post. Perhaps that is the reason

Comment: You don't need the `== true` bit. I'd use `.exists?` I bet the return type of the fetch isn't a nil object or an ActiveRecord object.

Comment: Hmm, I do not see any reason why it would not work, regardless of how you check for the record's existence. Maybe try using a debugger, like [pry](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails) and examine what's going on in the production code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the `redirect_to` instruction is not the last instruction in your controller, the redirect will never happen.

```
if @game.nil?
  redirect_to root_path
  return
end

render @game
```

Without the return, the `redirect_to` will be overridden by a `render`. You have to see it like this: Rails will not **immediately** redirect upon a **redirect_to** instruction. It will set the instruction somewhere and once your Controller returns, it will retrieve if there is a set action to do, if not, it will jump to the default action ("render action view")

Possibly would be nice if there was a warning that you overwrite your action if you have multiple `redirect`s/`render`s, but other than that, this is totally fine behaviour.

Regards.

**EDIT**

On a side note, if you're using Rails 4, use `Game.find_by(id: params[:id])` instead of `Game.where(id: params[:id]).first`.
If you simply want to check existance, `Game.exists?(params[:id])` is a nice way, as others have mentioned. `Game.find(params[:id])` will throw an error if `id` can't be found. A good hint would be to work with slugs as people might guess your games' IDs which is basically a security vulnerability.

Comment: Hmm, I have never heard of the requirement for the `redirect_to` to be the last executed line in the action method. I did a quick test (rails 4), and it is seems quite acceptable to place it pretty well anywhere in the body of the action method (though very odd, and you may see strange behaviour if it is not at the bottom). Ultimately, all the redirect does is set the location and response body, which you can see [here in the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb). Am I missing something?

Comment: I didn't know the source but now it's clear, yes. It just sets the `location`, `body` and `response`. It does nothing else! So if you overwrite these attributes the redirect will never happen since most browsers only follow the "Location" header if the status code is 302. Anyway, there is no magic behind it. If you have some misty code in your application that might overwrite these attributes your redirect might fail.

Answer (score 0):

Does your controller method continue after this if statement? `redirect_to` does NOT return from the method. If you want to halt execution right there and redirect, you need to explicitly return by doing:

```
if @game.nil?
  redirect_to root_path && return
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Just figured this out yes :( I thought a redirect_to would work as is, it seems I have several locations in code where im not using return hence thats the reason it fails

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Why would the redirection not proceed as expected if program flow continued past the invocation of `redirect_to`?

Comment: On a sidenote.. a 1 liner fails .. so written as redirect_to root_path && return unless Game.exists?(params[:id]. Why would it not be working as expected if you would use this one-liner?

Comment: I am not sure about the Ruby parser in this case. Try to use parentheses everywhere before you try stripping them off: `(redirect_to(root_path) && return) unless Game.exists?`.